# Can we navigate to some URL in interceptors in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors

I have to create a interceptor in which I have to identify the http request url and redirect to a particular url for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor's won't directly navigate to the URL for authentication.
U will have serve this purpose  by using guards.

Guards resolve the purpose of router navigation for authentication.

Then u can use basic HTTP authentication.